# Why is my code always allowing duplicate names?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, user-input

I have a question about writing a code that can check if what the user inputs (a string) is a duplicate of a string that an array already stored:

First of all I want to point out I checked with the question on here about duplicates but they are either answered with importing packages other than Scanner or checking duplicates in an already int or string stored arrays. This is different:

```
        int numberOfPigs = Integer.parseInt( keyboard.nextLine() );
        Pigs pigArray = new pigs[numberOfPigs];

        for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++){

            System.out.println("Pig name: " + (i+1));
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            String [] tempArray = new String [numberOfPigs];

            tempArray[i]=name;

            for (int k = i+1; k < pigArray.length; k++){

            while (tempArray[i].equals( tempArray[k])){
                    System.out.println("The ID is duplicate.");
                    tempArrays[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
                }
                System.out.println("Not a duplicate! Yay.");
            }
```

...code not over. the for loop with int i still has to go through several inputs from user before looping back to the beginning and go through i++ with taking in the next pig name. The rest part of the code I have no problem with, it's just that whenever i run this code, the duplicates are still allowed in... Any tips are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you do not want any duplicates why not just use a Set?

Comment: Because I'm a a beginner java programmer. I want to master for and while loops first before importing other packages. I didn't notice aliteralmind changed my title. It used to say no arraylist, set or hashmaps

Comment: Okay I solved your problem, you made 2 mistakes, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes in your code.

1. You were redeclaring your tempArray in your initial for loop.
2. You were counting up in your k loop when you should have been counting down.

   ```
   int numberOfPigs = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
   Pigs pigArray = new pigs[numberOfPigs];
   String[] tempArray = new String[numberOfPigs]; // I moved this here see
                                                       // comment below
   for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("Pig name: " + (i + 1));
   String name = keyboard.nextLine();
   // first problem was you were redeclaring your tempArray here
   // thereby erasing previous elements over every iteration of i
   tempArray[i] = name;
   for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) { // you need to count backwards
                           //you only check what was already entered for duplicates
                            // you were doing the opposite
   while (tempArray[i].equals(tempArray[k])) {
       System.out.println("The ID is duplicate.");
       tempArray[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
   }
   System.out.println(" Not a duplicate! Yay.");
   }// k loop
   }// i loop
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check this out and check out your comments. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3503794 I will be glad to explain any part of the code if you are confused as to anything. Do you see how your k loop was all logically messed up? You were trying to check nothing for no reason. You want to go backwards into the array not forwards because you are checking for duplicates of things previously entered.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read your comments and I now understand how to avoid re declaring my tempArray ( which before I thought that would be a problem but didn't know how to fix it) and benefit of going backwards (this part is the main reason I needed help. I had no idea what exactly should be inside the parenthesis). I see now what I must do. Thanks again CodeCamper.

Comment: @user3503794 Remember to use the debugger in eclipse. I didn't notice you were declaring your array over and over again until I used the variable view in the debugger and I noticed the previous elements in the array were missing. As for the for loop just remember whatever you put at the end such as the k++ or k-- does not happen until the final closing bracket } this is important to understand when you type k>=0 you know it will hit 0 then when it goes to the bottom it will subtract to -1 and fail the next check this way we can reverse to 0(first element of the array)

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time I run into trouble :p

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberOfPigs = Integer.parseInt( keyboard.nextLine() );
Pigs pigArray = new pigs[numberOfPigs];

for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++){

   System.out.println("Pig name: " + (i+1));
   String name = keyboard.nextLine();


   String [] tempArray = new String [numberOfPigs];
```

`tempArray` is now an array with `numberOfPigs`, where each element is `null`.

```
   tempArray[i]=name;
```

Now the first element in `tempArray` is the user-input name, but all other elements are still `null`.

```
   for (int k = i+1; k < pigArray.length; k++){
```

Why are you using `pigArray.length`, yet you are not using `pigArray` in the loop at all?

```
      while (tempArray[i].equals( tempArray[k])){
```

In fact, you're comparing the first element in the array, which is not `null` (it's the user input), against all the other elements, which *are* `null`! Of course it won't think *anything* is a duplicate, because you're checking the it against a whole bunch of *nothing*.

Since the user-input name is never equal to `null`, that is being falsely interpreted as "not a duplicate", and allowed through.

```
         System.out.println("The ID is duplicate.");
         tempArrays[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
      }
   System.out.println("Not a duplicate! Yay.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and answering the question. I will see what I can do.

Comment: If you are still here I would like to ask a questions: I changed the second for loop to: for (int k = 0; int k < tempArray.length; k++) but I always ran into this problem because I want the first loop to skip going through this loop (since it will always be duplicate) and the second loop (second time taking a pig name) to go through that for loop so to check duplicates. I tried another for or while loop with no success. any tips?

Comment: I am here for about five more minutes.

Comment: Im sorry, I don't understand. Consider adding more information and code snippets to the bottom of your question, or posting a whole new question. But why not leave it "k + 1" if you want to skip the first element, instead of comparing it against itself, which of course is a "duplicate"?

Comment: ok i will try some stuff then post a new question. Thank you .

Comment: @user3503794 I solved your problem, check my answer.